# Display rating star in Django with fontawesome v5.13

Tags: django, django-templates

I am writing a website with django  and in this website, I periodically ask users to rate platform. I store the ratings with `models.FloatField()` in my database.
Now my problem is how to display the stars.

If I have something like 3.5 as the rating value, then in my html page, I should have 3 full stars and the fourth star should be half while the fifth (also the last) should be empty star

How can I achieve this with fontawesome v5.13

In fontawesome v4.7, one can do something like below

```
<span>
    <i class="fa fa-star{% if review.rating == 0.5 %}-half-o{% elif review.rating < 1 %}-o {% endif %}" aria-hidden="true"></i>

    <i class="fa fa-star{% if review.rating == 1.5 %}-half-o{% elif review.rating < 2 %}-o {% endif %}" aria-hidden="true"></i>

    <i class="fa fa-star{% if review.rating == 2.5 %}-half-o{% elif review.rating < 3 %}-o {% endif %}" aria-hidden="true"></i>

    <i class="fa fa-star{% if review.rating == 3.5 %}-half-o{% elif review.rating < 4 %}-o {% endif %}" aria-hidden="true"></i>

    <i class="fa fa-star{% if review.rating == 4.5 %}-half-o{% elif review.rating < 5 %}-o {% endif %}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
```

But the `fa fa-star-0` and `fa fa-star-half-0` is no longer available in `fontawesome v5.13` which is the version am using, instead we now have `far fa-star` and `fas fa-star-half-alt`

So how can I achieve the same thing with `fontawesome v5.13`

Answer (score 0):

Have a template file for each rating value:

```
##### stars_0.5.html
<i class="fa fa-star-half-o"=></i> # half star
<i class="far fa-star"></i> #hollow star
<i class="far fa-star"></i> #hollow star
<i class="far fa-star"></i> #hollow star
<i class="far fa-star"></i> #hollow star

##### stars_1.0.html
<i class="fas fa-star"=></i> # full star
<i class="far fa-star"></i> #hollow star
<i class="far fa-star"></i> #hollow star
<i class="far fa-star"></i> #hollow star
<i class="far fa-star"></i> #hollow star

##### stars_1.5.html
<i class="fas fa-star"=></i> # full star
<i class="fa fa-star-half-o"=></i> # half star
<i class="far fa-star"></i> #hollow star
<i class="far fa-star"></i> #hollow star
<i class="far fa-star"></i> #hollow star

etc..
```

Then in your view:

```
...
stars_template = f'stars_{str(rating)}.html'
context = {"stars_template": stars_template, ...}
```

And in your template:

```
... other html
{% include stars_template %}
... other html
```

Comment: I edited the question to include more details. I added a sample of how it can be done with `fontawesome v4.7`. Do you know how I can do same thing with `fontawesome v5.13`